# Get current month from Room Database

Tags: android, database, android-room

I don't know how to get data from Room database which gets the current month

I try this but it doesn't work, the data keeps show the other month

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM transaksi WHERE strftime('%m', tanggal) = :tgl")
fun getData(tgl : String): List<Transaksi>
```

So the `tanggal` variable is `Date` type. I'm using TypeConverters for it, Is the date's format important? Because I format the date to "dd-MM-yyyy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Int` for preserve `Date` try this method:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM transaksi WHERE datetime(tanggal/1000,'unixepoch','start of month') = datetime(:dateOfMonth/1000,'unixepoch','start of month')")
fun getData(dateOfMonth : Date): List<Transaksi> // <-- changed parameter's type to Date
```

So you put date in method (any in needed month) and get all rows with date in the same month

**UPDATE**

For getting the same result by month and year you can add another method in DAO (but without any annotation) and call `getDate` method mentioned above:

```
fun getDataByMonthAndYear(month: Int, year: Int): List<Transaksi> {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.set(year, month , 1)
    val date = calendar.time
    return getData(date)
}
```

Comment: so if I'm using this query it will work to get month and year? or I need to change it too?
@Query("SELECT * FROM transaksi WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', tanggal) = :month-:year")
    fun getDataByMonthAndYear(month:String,year:String) : LiveData<List<Transaction>>

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I honestly don't like this approach with strings' formatting. But you can try. Or you can call inside your `getDataByMonthAndYear` the same `getData` method, but change its parameters to Int - `getDataByMonthAndYear(month:Int, year:Int)` (this method would be plain method without Room annotations), use Java's `Date` transformations to get `Date` value and then call `getDate` method.

Comment: then how I declare that month and year in query?

Comment: hey I got a problem with your query, the problem is when I insert data with day 1 they always show in another month, for example, I'm inserting data to 1 November 2020 but it shows at date October 2020

Comment: Maybe it's because of user's timezone. Try to set `...,'start of month', 'localtime')` instead

Comment: I changed my TypeConverter to string and date also update my query using strftime instead of datetime

Answer (score 0):

I Think the return type should not be the Table itself, be specific about the return type:

Try:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM transaksi WHERE strftime = :tgl")
fun getData(tgl : String): List<String>
```